# How can we do a specific input that can make a drawing/symbol?

Tags: python

So I'm trying to make a code where you enter an odd number in an input then the output is a lovely pattern of stars.

An example:

Input: 5

Output:

```
*        *
***    ***
**********
***    ***
*        *
```

If you don't understand, it starts with 1 star, then 3, then 5, then three, then 1. Like a pattern.

But I'm kinda stuck on how to make it. Can anyone help?

Thanks :D

Comment: All of your lines have the same length, they are made of n stars, enough spaces, and n stars again. Devise a formula and code it.

Comment: use `for`-loop to repeat it with bigger and bigger value - ie. `range(1, 5, 2)`, or `2*i-1` for i=1,2,3,

Comment: It does not answer it btw. But thanks though.

Comment: it is place for commens. And comments doesn't have to answer/solve. Place for answers is below.

Comment: BTW: you can split problem on two parts - in first number of start is bigger and bigger - ie. `range(1, 5, 2)`, in second part number of start is lower and lower - ie. `range(5, 0, -2)`

Comment: @furas check my answer below

Comment: @Phantom you have an answer below.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη - nice but you ask for `userinput` but never use this value - so you can remove this part or use this variable in code. Instead of `if item= 5` you can put second `for`-loop after first loop instead of putting inside.

Comment: @furas the OP didn't asked to use the value. he want the stars to be in stable shape.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη frankly, OP wrote `enter an odd number` and OP put `5` only as example. But if you create only for `5` then still you don't need `input('Insert Num ')` in your code :)

Comment: @furas ops got it now.

Comment: @αԋɱҽԃαмєяιcαη your code was close. Few changes and you will create correct answer.

Comment: @furas i think it's done now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
userinput = int(input('Insert Number: '))


if userinput % 2 == 1:
    for item in range(1, (userinput + 1), 2):
        print('{:<{}}{:>{}}'.format('*' * item,
                                    userinput, '*' * item, userinput))
    for item in range((userinput - 2), 0, -2):
        print('{:<{}}{:>{}}'.format('*' * item,
                                    userinput, '*' * item, userinput))
else:
    print("That's Not Odd Number")
```

Comment: Thanks, but can you please explain the {:<{}}{:>{}} stuff like that with the .format and stuff like that, because I didn't really understand what you were trying to do there.  Thanks though :D

Comment: well format string is holding the variables. for example `a,b,c,d = 1,2,3,4` so `print('{}{}{}{}.format(a,b,c,d)')` will print `1 2 3 4`. if my answer if happy you so you can accept it by select the `✓ `mark beside the question.

Comment: good job. +1. But I still think you could skip `if item == userinput:` and run second `for`-loop` after first loop, not inside.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly shorter approach:

```
def draw_star(n, c = True):
   for i in range(1, n, 2):
      print(f'{"*"*([n-i-1, i][c])}{" "*(2*n-(2*([n-i-1, i][c])))}{"*"*([n-i-1, i][c])}')
   if c:
      print('*'*(2*n))

draw_star(5)
draw_star(5, False)
```

Output:

```
*        *
***    ***
**********
***    ***
*        *
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you already got some great answers but I thought I'd I'd simplify it and give you a place to start from rather than the answer:

```
for x in range(1,6):
    print('*' * x)


for x in range(6,0,-1):
    print('*' * x)
```

output:

```
*
**
***
****
*****
******
*****
****
***
**
*
```

Update, because you want the solution:

```
total_width = 10 # play with this number

for x in range(1, round(total_width/2)):
    print(('*' * x) + (' ' * (total_width - (x * 2))) + ('*' * x))

for x in range(round((total_width/2)-2), 0, -1):
    print(('*' * x) + (' ' * (total_width - (x * 2))) + ('*' * x))
```

output

```
*        *
**      **
***    ***
****  ****
**********
****  ****
***    ***
**      **
*        *
```

as a neat function:

```
def bowtie(width=10, char="*"):
    for x in range(1, round(width / 2)):
        print((char * x) + (' ' * (width - (x * 2))) + (char * x))

    for x in range(round((width / 2) - 2), 0, -1):
        print((char * x) + (' ' * (width - (x * 2))) + (char * x))

bowtie(6, '^')
```

output

```
^    ^
^^  ^^
^    ^
```

Comment: Thank you so much! But I was looking for a bow tie instead of a pyramid.

Comment: Added the solution, thought you may be able to figure it out from the example